# "This dependancy was not found" when i try to import from ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I try to create a custom plugin. Wheni import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image' i get an error

```
This dependency was not found:

* -!../../../css-loader/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!../../../postcss- loader/src/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-2!./@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme- lark/theme/mixins/_rwd.css in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3- 
1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-3- 
2!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/theme/textalternativeform.css

To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../css- 
loader/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!../../../postcss-loader/src/index.js?? 
ref--6-oneOf-3-2!./@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark/them
```

How should i fix it? I've installed this package https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark and there is no effect.

Comment: Hi! Similar issues were discussed in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1412 but no one provided any details so far (neither did you) so we're unable to reproduce it. If you could create a sample repository in which this problem can be reproduced, we will be able help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created the vue.config.js file and included the details from

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html

Make sure @ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark is installed

npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark

That should then fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

after modified the `vue.config.js` make sure you are re-run again your VUE application

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got same error because I did not follow the guide very well. After read it I had to run this:

```
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2 @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils postcss-loader@4 raw-loader@4
```

For specific modules selected, something like this:

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic @ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment @ckeditor/ckeditor5-autosave  @ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder @ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font @ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading @ckeditor/ckeditor5-image @ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent @ckeditor/ckeditor5-link @ckeditor/ckeditor5-list @ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph @ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office @ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format @ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing @ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles
```

Then, in my case I use VUE 2+ version, so I had to modify the `vue.config.js` file, accorging the official documentation: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v2.html

Plase check the documentation with your specific framework: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/overview.html